# Google Sheets trendline broken; file unavailable

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-charts-trendlines

In Google Sheets, I've created a line graph.

[image: graph screen shot]

I want to add a trend line. I do so by clicking the blue line and selecting `Linear` from the trendline dropdown.

No trendline appears. Then when I right click on the graph and select `Trendline 0` like so

[image: menu]

Then this appears

[image: error message: "File unavailable - Sorry, there's a problem with this file. Please reload."]

My love of trends makes this particularly infuriating.

I cannot find anybody with the same issue anywhere...

Comment: Did you follow the link to report the error? I've seen elsewhere that Google is having some network issues. Are you caught up in that?

Comment: That link directs me to an FAQ page, and there is no way to lodge an error. I was a little weirded out by that.

Nevertheless, I highly doubt this is a network issue. I can load the documents just fine. It's the actual app that's having some sort of difficulty rendering trend lines

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and frustration (other than my error now says "Unable to load file" rather than "File unavailable", but that's probably just because it's been almost 2 years and they've changed their message). Solved for me by unchecking "Aggregate column A" on the Chart types tab of the Chart Editor.

Something else you may have to do if column A contains date-like info. In my spreadsheet, I had a 6-digit number representing `yyyymm` ranging from `201506` to 201701 but the graph treated them as integers (as I suppose it should) jumping 89 spaces between 201512 and 201601. Checking that Aggregate column A box seemed to solve it immediately and gave me back my "months", but then I found later that adding trendlines was not working. If that's also your problem, you'll have to change date-like values to actual date values like `2017-01-01`, and then just use custom number formatting to display them like `yyyymm` or whatever you want.